# Ubuntu 20.04 - xca starts with warnings

Tags: certificate, linux

Some months ago I used the xca tool to create some test certificates on a Ubuntu 18.04.
Today I've upgraded Ubuntu to 20.04 and checked installed software if they are working or not.
The xca starts with two warnings:

> The Object '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3:msUPN:Microsoft Universal Principal Name' from file /usr/share/xca/oids.txt line 10 is already known as
> '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3:msUPN:Microsoft User Principal Name' and should be removed.

> The Object '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2:msSmartcardLogin:Microsoft Smartcardlogin' from file /usr/share/xca/oids.txt line 15 is already known as
> '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2:msSmartcardLogin:Microsoft Smartcard Login' and should be removed.

Have you got any idea what are these? Just because the referred file (/usr/share/xca/oids.txt) contains a warning, not to edit that file.
I've tried to delete all related files (apt-get remove --purge ...; rm -rf ~/.xca/ ; etc), and then reinstall it and restart with no default database, but these warnings remained at the start...
Because the Google doesn't know anything about it, I'm a little bit helpless...
Is this an error, caused by the upgrading procedure?
Or is it a bug in the xca package?
Or... ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do any Google search? Cause:
[Github xca issues 203](https://github.com/chris2511/xca/issues/203)

Basically it’s due to a change in Debians OpenSSL package.